# How to detect low and high flow outliers with seasonal time series data in R?

Tags: r, time-series, outliers, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset recording daily river flow from 1976 to 2017. I want to find out unusually high (potential flood) or low (potential drought) flow values from that datatset. **What's the best way to identify such outliers?** *I define unusually high/low flow values as outliers as per the definition below: "An anomaly/outlier can be defined as a data point or collection of data points that don't seem to follow the same pattern as the rest of the data.".*

I must account for the seasonality of my data, where higher flow values are expected in winter and autumn while lower values are expected in spring and summer.

Below is an example using the `anomalize` R package with the *twitter* algorithm, I am not sure if this is even capable of capturing low flows. Also is the `remainder` (output from the `anomalize()` function == observed value - trend) informative when comparing rivers with generally high flow values against river with small flow values?

Do you have any suggestion? (I would greatly appreciate a demonstration of the method recommended using the provided dataset)

```r
#install.packages("remotes")
#remotes::install_github("cvitolo/rnrfa")
library(rnrfa) #river flow data
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 4.1.1
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 4.1.1
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 4.1.1
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 4.1.1
library(metR) # season function
#> Warning: package 'metR' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'metR'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     cross

#get_data
info <- gdf(id = "202002")
df <- fortify(info) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rename(date = Index,
         flow = gdf) %>% 
  mutate(season = metR::season(date))

#plot: 
df %>% 
  ggplot()+
  aes(x = date, y = flow, group = 1, col = season)+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point(size = 0.7)
```

[image]

```r
#Anomaly detection:
library(anomalize)
#> == Use anomalize to improve your Forecasts by 50%! =============================
#> Business Science offers a 1-hour course - Lab #18: Time Series Anomaly Detection!
#> </> Learn more at: https://university.business-science.io/p/learning-labs-pro </>
anomalies <- df %>% 
  time_decompose(flow, 
                 method    = "twitter",
                 frequency = "1 week",
                 trend     = "3 months") %>% #season
  anomalize(remainder)
#> Converting from tbl_df to tbl_time.
#> Auto-index message: index = date
#> frequency = 7 days
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
#> median_span = 91 days

anomalies %>% 
  plot_anomaly_decomposition()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "flood," "drought," and "unusually high."  It *really* helps to have some meaningful characterization of these hydrological concepts, for otherwise there are a huge number of potential approaches yielding diverse solutions.  Can you fill us in?

Comment: Thanks, I added the following after my question: I define unusually high/low flow values as outliers as per the definition below: "An anomaly/outlier can be defined as a data point or collection of data points that don't seem to follow the same pattern as the rest of the data.".

I would expect such outliers to be values that are far from the expected value at time *t* based on the season and the 40 years of cyclical data we have. I will then personally check those outliers out and assess wether they could be droughts or flood but the main aim of this analysis is to detect the outliers.

Comment: My point is that "same pattern" is in the eye of the beholder.  You need to describe what you mean by "pattern."  As an example, the last time I did this kind of analysis I was working in a small river system within an arid environment where any changes of more than about 20% above seasonally predictable base flow would be attributed to flash flooding within tributaries.  It was relatively easy to estimate a threshold to identify floods.  That wouldn't work with a large river system in a tropical rainforest with its completely different hydrological regime.

Comment: *"20% above seasonally predictable base flow".*  
That sounds like a right approach. So how would you go about determining the  seasonally predictable base flow from the given data? Then I could always play around with the % treshold to see how that affects the number of outliers

Comment: Last time, I did it iteratively: pick a crude threshold, cut off above-threshold flows, model the remaining provisional base flows (I used a long-term trend, annual seasonality, and daily cycling), use that to construct an upper prediction limit for each individual cutoff flow, identify the chronological start and end of each such "excursion," eliminate all data in each such tentative flood period, and repeat.  It converged quickly and resulted in removing about 1 - 2% of all flows, which I felt was reasonable.  I could then explore and model the floods separately from the base regime.

Comment: (Continued) I did this separately at the different gauges I had along the river and then compared the results (accounting for the time lags for the flow to travel from one gauge to another) to settle on a final dataset and model.  It helped that I had 35 years of data (about 15% missing in various periods) sampled at 5 to 15 minute intervals most of that time. The analyses eventually were performed on 30-minute mean flows.